# How to check the state of rs.initiate

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing system using replica set of 3 members already running, I am trying to add another member, but I saw in the Doc that I need to run this command `rs.initiate()` fist before I can add another member `rs.add(“hostname03:27017”)`

Do I need to run `rs.initiate()` ?  I am assuming that I don't need to since I already have a replica set up & running. How do I check the status of rs.initiate if it has already been initiated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to. The `rs.initiate()` command is not much more than telling the instance you are connected to that it should set up everything for a replica set. In your case, this has already be done. So simply connect to the primary of your replica set and add the member.

Disclaimer: The following comes of the top of my head and I don't have the means of checking its correctness on my tablet.

Iirc, `rs.initiate()` is a shell helper. So you might be able to see what it is actually doing by issuing

```
rs.initiate
```

(Note the missing parenthesises) in the mongo shell.

Comment: Thx Markus! you are correct, I tested the process and rs.initiate() should be used mostly during a new implementation of mongo. In my case, I already have an existing replica set with 3 members running, and I needed to add another member. Thx.